# How to take one to rehabilation center without telling him?

Tags: family, india, substance-abuse, intervention

My dad drinks a lot and creates nuisances after that, when he's drunk. To try to end that I am planning to take him to a rehabilitation center.

If we ask him to come with us, he won't. What is a better way of doing that?

I'm planning to take him to the center when he's drunk and unconscious. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: This is called an [intervention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervention_(counseling)).

Comment: can you edit your question to include where you live? In some jurisdictions, alcohol rehab centres can't hold people against their will, so it's important for him to actually agree to going.

Comment: You should also add if he is in danger of harming himself or others, or causing property damage. In such situations legal action may be possible. It wouldn't be as good as getting him to want to sober up, but objectively this kind of reason makes sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unfortunately, this question appears to be asking “What should I do?”, which the community has [determined](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1310/31) to not be a good fit for Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange. We can’t decide for you what to do; after you determine what you want to do, we can help you with your goal, but we can’t make these decisions for you. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

This is a very difficult situation but like @SQB mentions, an [intervention](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Intervention_(counseling)) would be best to start out with.

Forcing him into rehab will not help him as much as you think it will. *He has to want* to beat the addiction for rehab to be most effective, as in, less likely for a relapse.

Intervention is meant to get the person to realize how much harm their addiction is causing themselves and their loved ones and therefore, encourage them to make the choice to go to rehab "on their own".

Dealing with a loved one's addiction is emotionally exhausting and takes a toll. I really hope you are able to get through to your father and help him make the choice to better his life.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the misfortune of taking a few friends to rehab... It's never easy, no matter how you do it.

In my experience, it's only the ones who've really hit bottom  hard that have any lasting success. More or less those that end up agreeing to go to rehab because they've run out of other options.

Often the best thing to do is the hardest thing to do when the afflicted person is someone close to you. Cut them off financially and emotionally till they're willing to get the help they need.

Alcoholics and addicts are a hard bunch to deal with when they're still using. Telling them that you're no longer willing to deal with them, until they get help, brings them a little closer to hitting bottom and limits the damage they can do till they're ready.

Answer (score 3):

I'd first call the rehabilitation center (maybe a few times) and ask them if there's anything you need to prepare first when bringing your father, and for suggestions along these lines.  I suspect they see families in a lot of different situations and can provide recommendations.